# How do I compile a module without an EntryPoint?

Tags: gwt, entry-point

I have a utility module for GWT which doesn't have an UI (hence, there is no class which inherits from `com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint`. When I try to compile this module with GWT 1.7.1, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Module has no entry points defined
```

How do I get rid of this error? Do I really have to define a dummy entry point? How did Google ever compile their own utility modules???

Comment: but you need at least one per application: is this covered?

Comment: Yep. I have an entry point in another module. I'm just stumped how I can compile a module without an EP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the `gwt-maven-plugin` Maven2 plugin to compile my code. I migrated the code from an old version of the `maven-googlewebtoolkit2-plugin` plugin. For the old plugin, I had to specify which modules were entry points like so:

```
                <compileTargets>
                    <param>com.project.module.Module</param>
                </compileTargets>
```

For the new plugin, it's

```
                <module>com.project.module.Module</module>
```

Since the plugin couldn't find which modules to compile, it search for "*.gwt.xml" and compiled all of them into "UI modules" (which must have an entry point).

Answer (score 5):

Utility Jars do not need to be compiled by GWT.

If you just want to reuse this as a library in other GWT applications then you just have to jar the .class and .java files in one jar and make sure that you have a .gwt.xml that says where the client source is. If you follow the conventions (client classes in client) then you can get away with just otherwise you need to specify a tag for the client package

Then make sure that you inherit this .gwt.xml in the projects where you want to compile an entry point.

Comment: The annoying thing is that if you accidentally use code that's not available in the GWT client, then it won't cause an error until you try to compile it into the full app. Thus, you can produce utility jars, as you call them, that aren't actually valid for use by GWT. Is there any way around that?

Answer (score 4):

No you don't need an EntryPoint. Here is an example of one of my modules that doesn't have one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module>
    <source path="grid" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>
</module>
```

The short answer is you don't compile code in modules. GWT just needs them as source code. When you compile your main module (the one with the entry point) it uses the source from any other modules you have inherited in your .gwt.xml file to compile the entire project.

Comment: +1 That didn't solve my issue but pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

We've got a utilities module, which constructs & handles some common UI elements, and a bunch of javascript/json common tasks.

It looks like what we did (also migrated from the totsp plugin to the codehaus plugin somewhere along the line) was to include an entry point in the util module; it was just empty.  (It includes the comment "Intentional no-op").

Then the pom just refers to the thing as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If using eclipse GWT plugin just remove the module without an EntryPoint from the moduleslist that pops up just before compiling.