# Can I force GWT compilation without entry point? (To validate compatibility to GWT)

Tags: java, gwt

This question is related to, but not a duplicate of, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808197/how-do-i-compile-a-module-without-an-entrypoint).

My issue is slightly different; I have a "utility module", shared between the client and server code, and it contains *no GWT-specific code*.

I understand that normally, all the sources are pulled into one specific project, where everything is compiled together. But there is one issue with that: *I only get to know if my utility project is "GWT compatible", when I compile the main project*. This is way too late; I haven't even got around to start on the main project, but I want to know before I make a "commit" to my SCM, that my utility project is "GWT compatible".

In other words, I want to validate the utility project for GWT compatibility, *independently from it's use in a separate project (module)*.

There's a large part of the JRE that is not covered by GWT, and it is particularly likely in a utility module that non-GWT-compatible classes or method be used. That is what I want to validate against.

EDIT: I *could* add a "dummy entry point", I suppose, but that makes the project depend on GWT, which I don't want to, since it is "general" code, also to be used by people that don't use GWT. If it matters, I use Maven as build system.

EDIT2: No matter what I do, I will only get real compilation/validation with an entry point (does NOT need to reference any of the classes). Neither <force>true</force>, nor <failOnError>true</failOnError> will do. Is there a way I can define that entry point, for the *shared project*, such that only gwt-maven-plugin sees it, but not javac (so as not to add an unneeded dependency in the Java code)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler actually always visits all code on the source path (note: not quite the same as the classpath), by starting at the requested module with any `<source>` tags, and then checking each `<inherits>` along the way. If it finds something that isn't compatible or isn't compilable, it will mark it as broken, and move on - as long as nothing actually depends on it (i.e. an EntryPoint, or something that an EntryPoint depends on) you'll just see this message:

```
   Validating newly compiled units
      Ignored 1 unit with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
```

If you include that `-strict` flag, the compile will actually fail when it hits something that can't be included correctly.

---

This work is done in the very early stages of the compile, while constructing the TypeOracle, which is used for Generators, long before any JS is built. That type oracle is passed to generators, which need to be able to ask questions like 'what interfaces on the sourcepath have a JSO implementation' and 'what are all possible subclasses of List'. Generators can do a huge number of things, including emit even more types which then need to be parsed, compiled, and the process continues until a full JProgram is created of all possible types, based on the current set of modules.

That JProgram then gets compiled down based on what can be reached from the roots - the entrypoint, as well as a few other details such as how to emulate Java details like casts, arrays, longs, exceptions, etc.

If `-strict` was not specified, and the compiler ends up needing to reach something which is unavailable due to earlier compilation problems, that is the time you find out. Using `-strict` to stop earlier will help ensure that you catch those issues sooner.

---

One more fun fact: By default, with `com.google.gwt.user.User` in your module (or any other `<inherits>` that depends on it), you already have an entrypoint, or several! These do some quick checking that your page is working correctly, such as using a strict doctype, or the browser actually matching the expected `user.agent` setting. This means that it is usually possible to compile a module even without an entrypoint (except with `gwt-maven-plugin:compile`, which will not consider a module for compilation just by those built-in ones).

---

EDIT: Okay, even one more: From http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html, combined with `-strict`, it looks like you can force the validation to run without actually compiling to JS:

```
-validateOnly            Validate all source code, but do not compile
```

Comment: The problem with the -strict flag is that it shows validation errors even if the code is not used by GWT, which defeats the purpose of the OP. Unless, of course, he is willing to inspect each error manually and decide what to do about it.

Comment: In either case, thank you for this detailed explanation.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I see your point, but a standalone module can't know if some incompatible part of itself will be required by a future module that may inherit it, so there is no way to allow *some* incompatibility without knowing what will be required. If I ask you to fill 10 boxes, but only check 3, and you only fill some without knowing which ones I will check, how do you fill the right ones? In general in a case like this, I'd rather all code marked as client-compatible actually is client-compatible, needed or not, since I might try to use it someday.

Comment: Agreed. I also keep my shared code 100% GWT-compatible.

Comment: The standard GWT pattern of dumping all your code in the same project causes mixups of Maven dependencies. If I break out client, server, and shared code, then @ColinAlworth solution cause no problem for me.

Comment: I still have a small problem; could you have a look at "EDIT2", and tell me if this is possible, and how?

Comment: I believe you are correct, though I haven't used that option myself. From looking at `com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile#validate` which is called by `com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler#run` if that flag is set, I see that it constructs a ModuleDef, does the precompile, then if strict is active, fails with a log message if there were any issues. If there were not, it continues into `com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler#precompile` which does the JProgram to JSProgram work, and if nothing blew up, considers it to be valid. The optimizationlevel flag could be used to limit how much this does.

Comment: Looking at Edit2 now, yep, looks like you are using maven, which runs into the issue I described in my post. There are a few workarounds: Add a dummy entrypoint which does nothing, make a dummy module *and* an entrypoint, only for the purposes of testing to keep the real module clean, or use the `exec-maven-plugin:exec` goal to run the `com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler` main class, with whatever args you would like. If you need more info, let me know, I can add to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've come to the realization that "everything is well"; if I always break my project in shared, server, client, then I always have a client module that depends on "shared", and that seems enough to test "shared". Since I always build all 3 together, there is no risk of checking in invalid code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible because the GWT compiler does not compile any unused code.

This means that your shared utility "module" may have code in it that is not compatible with GWT, but it will not cause any problems as long as GWT code never calls such incompatible classes or methods. Without an entry point GWT compiler won't know which code is used and which is not - it will assume that all of it is unused.

Comment: So, even if I added a "dummy" entry point, GWT would still not compile my code, because it wasn't referenced, not even indirectly, from the entry point, right? If so, then there really is no way to force code validation, I suppose.

Comment: Correct. You can, however, create a dummy entry point that references all the classes/methods that you want validated. It's almost like writing unit tests.